# Error: node.js not compiled with openssl crypto support

Tags: node.js, openssl, websocket

**I'm a novice with node.js, but have been trying to get a simple websockets server running. When I try and run an example server, I get the error:
"Error: node.js not compiled with openssl crypto support."
When I run ./configure, I get:**

Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++

Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp

Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar

Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib

Checking for g++                         : ok

Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/bin/gcc

Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar

Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib

Checking for gcc                         : ok

Checking for library dl                  : yes

Checking for openssl                     : yes

Checking for library util                : yes

Checking for library rt                  : yes

--- libeio ---

Checking for library pthread             : yes

Checking for function pthread_create     : yes

Checking for function pthread_atfork     : yes

Checking for futimes(2)                  : yes

Checking for readahead(2)                : yes

Checking for fdatasync(2)                : yes

Checking for pread(2) and pwrite(2)      : yes

Checking for sendfile(2)                 : yes

Checking for sync_file_range(2)          : yes 
--- libev ---
Checking for header sys/inotify.h        : yes

Checking for function inotify_init       : yes

Checking for header sys/epoll.h          : yes

Checking for function epoll_ctl          : yes

Checking for header port.h               : not found

Checking for header poll.h               : yes

Checking for function poll               : yes

Checking for header ['sys/types.h', 'sys/event.h'] : not found

Checking for header sys/queue.h                    : yes

Checking for function kqueue                       : not found

Checking for header sys/select.h                   : yes

Checking for function select                       : yes

Checking for header sys/eventfd.h                  : yes

Checking for function eventfd                      : yes

Checking for SYS_clock_gettime                     : yes

Checking for library rt                            : yes

Checking for function clock_gettime                : yes

Checking for function nanosleep                    : yes

Checking for function ceil                         : yes

Checking for fdatasync(2) with c++                 : yes

**Which implies openssl is installed. Can anyone give me specific advice or instructions as to how to solve this error?
Thank you.**

Comment: Did you compile node yourself or are you using a downloaded binary?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you installed nodejs from source, and you did not have openssl installed. To fix it install openssl and then re-install nodejs.